# Why does this line of code not open a new tab?

Tags: javascript

I have many lines of code that open a new web page in a new tab using  but this generated line of code overwrites the current page.

```
<button 
    onclick='location.href="http://www.jaguar.com.au/"' 
    target='_blank'>Jaguar Web Site
</button>
```

As I mentioned it is generated and there may be many of them. While trying to find an answer I noticed there is a way to do it with CSS but do not want to try it due to the unknown quantity of buttons.

I have tried it with the / removed from au/ moved it to after the style and removed style with no success.

Comment: Because `target` isn't a valid attribute for button elements, and assigning to `window.location` always changes the location of the current window/tab. It looks like you should use a simple link instead.

Comment: the javascript in the `onclick` event does what it does, here just redirecting. the `target='_blank'` works, if you let the browser handle everything with native behaviour. Long story short: Use `<A>` with `href` and `target`

Comment: css will not change the behavior of browser loading a new url

Comment: Where did you find a solution that uses CSS to open a new tab??? Please link

Comment: Changing the location.href does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Bergi: sorry I cannot find it again but it was in one of stackoverflow answers to not too similar question

Comment: I am unable to use < a > because they are in multi-page scrolling header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "generated" but the proper way to redirect is to go for the standard "a" tag:

```
<a href="http://www.jaguar.com.au/" target='_blank'>Jaguar Web Site</a>
```

Anything but this shouldn't be acceptable and shouldn't be used.

Comment: The buttons are created dynamically depending on how many are needed. It looks like I have to use < a > tags instead. Thank you